# Script user interface may not be accessible. WCAG 2.0 (Level AA)

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

I am trying to make my site accessibility compatible.

I am using 
[achecker.ca](https://achecker.ca/checker/index.php) to see my errors.

For some reason, all of my script tags are shown as potential error according to [WCAG 2.0 (Level AA)](https://achecker.ca/guideline/view_guideline.php?id=8) Section 2.1, Success Criteria 2.1.1, Check ID 89.

I need to get rid of these potential errors, but personally I do not know how can I make a script accessible that its only job is assigning an object. Like this script for example:

```
<script>
    window.dataLayer = [{
        "page_details": {
            "url": "\/us\/social-channels\/",
            "name": "Social channels"
        },
    }];
</script>
```

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6):

Looking at this specific issue, [Check ID 89](https://achecker.ca/checker/suggestion.php?id=89), it says:

> **Short Description**
>   This error will be generated for all `script` elements.

and then they have two examples, one passing, one failing.

> **Pass Examples**
>   Does not contain a `script` element.
>   **Fail Examples**
>   Contains a `script` element.

So according to the doc, **every** `<script>` is going to be marked as a "potential" problem and there's no way to prevent the warning (short of removing the `<script>`).

Personally, as an accessibility specialist, I think that warning is wrong.  Scripts should not be flagged.  If you had code where you have a mouse event handler, then that would definitely be a WCAG 2.1.1 problem.  But flagging a script generically does not mean anything.

Comment: Programmatically determining if some JavaScript does anything which cause could an accessibility problem is an area rife with either false positives and false negatives.

Comment: yes, exactly.  the false positives just cause extra work and make a bad name for accessibility

Answer (score 3):

"Potential problems" means that you have to check manually. This does not mean that you have any error.